# Problem filtering data upon choosing an item from combo box WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have two datagrid's in two different tabitems. The datagrid in first tabitem displays some specific data on app load and should get updated if the data changes, pretty simple. The second tabitem's datagrid should be empty on app load but when an item is selected/typed from the combo box then it should filter the data as per that combo box selected item and show on the filtered data on datagrid of second tabitem (maintaining MVVM pattern).

This is what I've tried:

XAML

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Pending Bills">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredBills}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Vendor"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=Party, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Width="275"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Bill No."
                        Binding="{Binding Path=BillNo, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Width="275"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
                ......
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Filtered Bills">
    ........
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding AllBills}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Vendor"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=Party, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Width="275"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Bill No."
                        Binding="{Binding Path=BillNo, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Width="275"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
                    ......
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox x:Name="cmbBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCBItem}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

A base viewmodel to enable the `PropertyChangedEventHandler`

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Basic model:

```
public class Bills : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    private string _party;
    public string Party
    {
        get
        {
            return _party;
        }
        set
        {
            _party = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Party");
        }
    }

    private string _billNo;
    public string BillNo
    {
        get
        {
            return _billNo;
        }
        set
        {
            _billNo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BillNo");
        }
    }

    .......

}
```

The billsviewmodel and a helper data access class called Model:

```
public class BillsViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public BillsViewModel()
        {
            cvsAll.Source = m.AllBills;
            cvsFiltered.Source = m.FilteredBills;
        }

        Model m = new Model();

        CollectionViewSource cvsAll = new CollectionViewSource();
        public ICollectionView AllBills
        {
            get { return cvsAll.View; }
        }


        public List<string> ComboItems
        {
            get { return m.UniqueValues(); }
        }

        CollectionViewSource cvsFiltered = new CollectionViewSource();
        public ICollectionView FilteredBills
        {
            get { return cvsFiltered.View; }
        }


        private string _selectedCBItem;
        public string SelectedCBItem
        {
            get { return _selectedCBItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedCBItem = value;
                cvsFiltered.Source = m.GetBills_Pen(value);
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCBItem");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        private List<Bills> _allBills;

        public List<Bills> AllBills
        {
            get
            {
                if (_allBills == null) LoadAllBillsFromDatabase();
                
                return _allBills;
            }
        }

        private List<Bills> _filteredBills;

        public List<Bills> FilteredBills
        {
            get
            {
                if (_filteredBills == null) LoadUnpaidBillsFromDatabase();

                return _filteredBills;
            }
        }

        public void LoadAllBillsFromDatabase()
        {
            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=Bills.db;");
            SQLiteCommand sqlCom = new SQLiteCommand(@"Select * From billdata", m_dbConnection);
            SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlCom);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            _allBills = new List<Bills>();
            
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                _allBills.Add(new Bills()
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"]),
                    Party = (string)row["Party"],
                    BillNo = (string)row["BillNo"],
                    .......
                });
                
            }
            m_dbConnection.Close();
        }

        public void LoadUnpaidBillsFromDatabase()
        {
            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=Bills.db;");
            SQLiteCommand sqlCom = new SQLiteCommand(@"Select * From billdata where PaidOn != ''", m_dbConnection);
            SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlCom);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            _filteredBills = new List<Bills>();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                _filteredBills.Add(new Bills()
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"]),
                    Party = (string)row["Party"],
                    BillNo = (string)row["BillNo"],
                    .......
                });

            }
            m_dbConnection.Close();
        }

        public List<string> UniqueValues()
        {
            return _allBills.Select((s) => s.Party).Distinct().OrderBy((s) => s).ToList();
        }
         

        public List<Bills> GetBills_Pen(string filterValue)
        { 
            return _allBills.FindAll(s => s.Party == filterValue).ToList();
        }
    }
```

There are 2 issues:

1. The datagrid on 2nd tabitem is displaying all data on app load
2. When I select or type a valid item in the combo box the datagrid on 2nd tabitem is not showing the filtered data.

Have I not implemented the `ICollectionView` the right way or what am I doing wrong here and most importantly how do I fix this ?

Comment: @mm8 The "2nd tabitem" datagrid is supposed to show the `AllBills` filtered by the combo box selected item and on app load it is supposed to show nothing. When I select/type a valid combo box item then only it should filter on `AllBills` by `Party` name using the combo box text. Sorry for the confusing naming in bindings. BTW, what do you mean by you don't see any `ComboBox` ? It is right at the end of my XAML code..

Comment: `AllBills` returns all bills, doesn't it? So how is it supposed to "show nothing"? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @mm8 yes I agree, so how do I modify it to fit my needs or do I need to implement a different property? I also need to get the unique `Party` names as combo box itemsource based on `AllBills` as well. Am I over complicating things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I also added a function to ViewModelBase to make the code shorter

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected virtual void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}

public class BillsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<BillViewModel> _allBills;

    public BillsViewModel()
    {
        _allBills = m.AllBills;
        AllBills = new ListCollectionView(_allBills);
        ComboItems = _allBills.Select(b => b.Party).Distinct().OrderBy(b => b).ToList();
        FilteredBills = new ListCollectionView(_allBills)
        {
            Filter = o => ((BillViewModel)o).Party == SelectedCBItem
        };
    }

    Model m = new Model();

    public ICollectionView AllBills { get; private set; }
    public ICollectionView FilteredBills { get; private set; }

    public List<string> ComboItems { get; private set; }

    private string _selectedCBItem;
    public string SelectedCBItem
    {
        get { return _selectedCBItem; }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _selectedCBItem, value);
            FilteredBills.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me a c#5.0 version of your code ? Thanks

Comment: Isn't it c#5 legal already?

Comment: sorry forgot the get only was added later.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Maybe I'm not explaining it right or maybe my posted code is a bit confusing but, the datagrid in first tabitem should simply show the data from the query `@"Select * From billdata where PaidOn != ''"` and it does not need any filtering, it stays as it is unless I make some changes in the database table and then only it updates if required. The datagrid in the second tabitem should be empty on app load and is what should show the filtered data using the combo box selected item when I select/type a valid item.

Comment: My naming convention is a bit messed up lol :)

Comment: i can't test it right now but the code should do that because there are 2 different listcollectionviews

Comment: Do I need to change something in the `Model` class ? `private List<Bills> _allBills;` is already declared in it. Also, I think `List<BillViewModel>` should be `List<Bills>` and `((BillViewModel)o).Party` should be `((Bills)o).Party` in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245618/discussion-between-firo-and-tamal-banerjee).

Answer (score -1):

Using the approach shown by @Firo I've managed to successfully implement in my app(so I'm marking his answer as accepted) and here is what I ended up with(in case it helps anyone who might have similar issues)

```
public class Model
{
    private List<Bills> _sBills;

    public List<Bills> SBills
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sBills == null) LoadAllBillsFromDatabase();
            
            return _sBills;
        }
    }

    

    public List<Bills> FilteredBills { get; private set; }

    public void LoadAllBillsFromDatabase()
    {
        SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=Bills.db;");
        SQLiteCommand sqlCom = new SQLiteCommand(@"Select * From billdata", m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlCom);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        _sBills = new List<Bills>();
        
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            _sBills.Add(new Bills()
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"]),
                            Party = (string)row["Party"],
                            BillNo = (string)row["BillNo"],
                            BillDt = (string)(row["BillDt"]),
                            Amt = (string)row["Amt"],
                            DueDt = (string)(row["DueDt"]),
                            PaidOn = (string)(row["PaidOn"])
                        });
            
        }
        m_dbConnection.Close();
    }

}

public class BillsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    
    private List<Bills> _allBills;

    public BillsViewModel()
    {
        _allBills = m.SBills;
        AllBills = new ListCollectionView(_allBills)
        {
            Filter = o => ((Bills)o).PaidOn==""
        };
        ComboItems = _allBills.Select(b => b.Party).Distinct().OrderBy(b => b).ToList();
        FilteredBills = new ListCollectionView(_allBills)
        {
            Filter = o => ((Bills)o).Party == SelectedCBItem && ((Bills)o).PaidOn==""
        };
    }

    Model m = new Model();

    public ICollectionView AllBills { get; private set; }
    public ICollectionView FilteredBills { get; private set; }

    public List<string> ComboItems { get; private set; }

    private string _selectedCBItem;
    public string SelectedCBItem
    {
        get { return _selectedCBItem; }
        set
        {

            SetValue(ref _selectedCBItem, value);
            FilteredBills.Refresh();
            
        }
    }
}
```

The itemsource in the datagrid in 1st tabitem is `AllBills` and itemsource in the datagrid in 2nd tabitem is `FilteredBills`